# Azure Storage Table Insert failing with "One of the request inputs is not valid"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying insert a dumb entity into an Azure Storage Table in javascript using [Insert Entity API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179433.aspx). I enabled CORS and managed to get my request authenticated, but my dead simple request is failing with `One of the request inputs is not valid.` message

Here is more details on the request:

```
Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:SharedKey <account>:<secret>
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:70
Content-type:application/json
DataServiceVersion:3.0;NetFx
Host:<account>.table.core.windows.net
If-Match:*
MaxDataServiceVersion:3.0;NetFx
Origin:http://localhost:6091
Referer:http://localhost:6091/
x-ms-date:Fri, 08 Jan 2016 06:23:29 GMT
x-ms-version:2013-08-15
```

Here is the request payload:

> {Message: "test", RowKey: "myrowkey", PartitionKey: "mypartitionkey"}

And here is the response, which has a HTTP status 400:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:x-ms-request-id,x-ms-version
Content-Type:application/json;odata=nometadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 08 Jan 2016 06:23:30 GMT
Server:Windows-Azure-Table/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
x-ms-request-id:4994f291-0002-004d-1cdd-49d7ff000000
x-ms-version:2013-08-15
```

with a body:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"InvalidInput","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"One
>   of the request inputs is not
>   valid.\nRequestId:4994f291-0002-004d-1cdd-49d7ff000000\nTime:2016-01-08T06:23:30.4716844Z"}}}

I have seen people complaining about this non-descriptive error message. However, I am pretty sure this request payload is fine. `RowKey` and `PartitionKey` do not have special characters and `Message` field doesn't have to provide its `odata` type (but believe me, I tried that too). I tried the payload provided as an example too, still the issue is there.

Comment: We use JavaScript/AJAX/CORS to manage table data extensively in our application. I just tried it there with your request payload and it worked just fine. Looks like some other issue. Will it be possible for you to share some code?

Comment: If possible, please share exactly the json body you tried to upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by trial and error method. The request header `If-Match:*` was the problem. I removed that header and it started working.

Azure definitely needs to get more explicit and clear about their documentation and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the example JSON body in the docs you linked to for insert entity you'll notice the keys should be in quotes. Try sending a body like the following:

{"Message": "test", "RowKey": "myrowkey", "PartitionKey": "mypartitionkey"}

Comment: Ah good, it actually did for me too but considering it didn't match the docs I still figured I'd suggest in case of any incidental other differences.

Comment: Also the PartitionKey and RowKey values need to be strings.